# (URGENT) Unable to log in: session retuned error code 1

Tags: greeter

[image: error after entering password]

Recently installed https://github.com/dahliaOS/pangolin_desktop from the instructions: https://docs.dahliaos.io/pangolin/pangolin-linux later ran uninstall.sh
Everything was smooth, no errors till now.

After immediately reboot facing this error after entering correct password. How to get into pantheon desktop?

Comment: Lost my previous guest account, i am op. Please consider helping me.

Comment: I just sudo deleted .Xauthority and recreated the file with the same name but without sudo (that is the user which you use)

Comment: To execute the commands you can use Ctrl+Alt+F2 to get into a virtual terminal

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26169)